Sorting timestamps from string 'alphabatical' to numbers in Python
I have data that I receive from a third-party application in which one of the columns is the timestamp, I get 48 timestamp values.
The problem is that I get the timestamps in alphabetical order, so number 10 appears above number 9 because it orders in an alphabetic way that it compares the first digit.
I need a way to rearrange the timestamps correctly, something like converting the numbers to two digits and comparing the numbers so it would sort them correctly based on the number.
Check the following attached images ‘SampleData1’ and ‘SampleData2’, the highlighted blue is how I receive the data ordered and the highlighted green is how I need the data to be organized.
SampleData1
SampleData2
I need to convert date into MM/DD/YYYY and also sort AM and PM

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Here's Python code to sort a list of date strings in the given format.
from datetime import datetime

# List of date strings
example_strings = [
    "5/10/24 12:00:03 AM",
    "5/11/24 12:00:34 PM",
    "5/9/24 09:30:00 AM",
    "5/11/24 06:15:22 AM"
]

# Define the format of the date string
date_format = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p"

# Convert the strings to datetime objects
timestamps = [datetime.strptime(date_str, date_format) for date_str in example_strings]

# Sort the list of datetime objects
sorted_timestamps = sorted(timestamps)

# Convert sorted datetime objects back to strings
sorted_date_strings = [timestamp.strftime(date_format) for timestamp in sorted_timestamps]

# Print sorted date strings:
for date_str in sorted_date_strings:
    print(date_str)

Output:
05/09/24 09:30:00 AM
05/10/24 12:00:03 AM
05/11/24 06:15:22 AM
05/11/24 12:00:34 PM


You cannot compare the strings lexicographically so you'll need to convert them to something that can be ordered. A datetime object is ideal for this use-case:
from datetime import datetime

example_strings = [
    "5/10/24 12:00:03 AM",
    "5/11/24 12:00:34 PM",
    "5/9/24 09:30:00 AM",
    "5/11/24 06:15:22 AM"
]

FMT = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p"

def key(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s, FMT)

print(*sorted(example_strings, key=key), sep="\n")

Output:
5/9/24 09:30:00 AM
5/10/24 12:00:03 AM
5/11/24 06:15:22 AM
5/11/24 12:00:34 PM

Note:
This technique does not alter the original strings
